# No sound on a Studio XPS 1647 

Tags: sound

I just installed Ubuntu 11 Server with LXDE. I found that there was no sound. What do I do?

Following [Sound Troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting)

```
jm@jm-laptop:~$ gnome-volume-control
** (gnome-volume-control:8750): WARNING **: Connection failed, reconnecting...

jm@jm-laptop:~$ sudo aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
  Subdevices: 0/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Generic [HD-Audio Generic], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

jm@jm-laptop:~$ find /lib/modules/`uname -r` | grep snd
/lib/modules/2.6.38-8-server/kernel/sound/pcmcia/vx/snd-vxpocket.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.38-8-server/kernel/sound/pcmcia/pdaudiocf/snd-pdaudiocf.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.38-8-server/kernel/sound/i2c/snd-cs8427.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.38-8-server/kernel/sound/i2c/snd-i2c.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.38-8-server/kernel/sound/i2c/other/snd-ak4117.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.38-8-server/kernel/sound/i2c/other/snd-ak4114.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.38-8-server/kernel/sound/i2c/other/snd-pt2258.ko
/lib/modules/2.6.38-8-server/kernel/sound/i2c/other/snd-ak4xxx-adda.ko
...

jm@jm-laptop:~$ lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0419
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 18) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: cfe00000-cfefffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000d0000000-00000000dfffffff
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp

00:1a.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 0419
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f0b05800 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: ehci_hcd
 ...

jm@jm-laptop:~$ wget -O alsa-info.sh http://alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh && bash ./alsa-info.sh
...
Your ALSA information is located at http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=711f054c4abd11e4c5570d5f7c315982f9d147e7
```

The contents of the URL http://pastie.org/1929819

Now what?

Comment: Did you get up to the step in troubleshooting that lists `alsamixer`? Run that and make sure everything is turned up (use arrow keys, and don't forget to hit tab and check you haven't missed anything!) This has fixed this issue for me on many occasions.

Comment: Oh, and also make sure nothing is muted in there: `M` mutes/unmutes. If a channel is unmuted, then there is a green box underneath the volume slider. If the channel is muted, the box is grey.

Comment: ah now it works, I'm not sure why also? I havent did anything just started `alsamixer` saw that sound seems ok then tried going YouTube ... http://i.imgur.com/pJrbZ.png ... does just `alsamixer` do anything to enable sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that installing

```
gnome-media pulseaudio
```

seems to fix this

Answer (score 0):

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 64bits and I recently installed XFCE-4 Desktop. When I first logged in xfce-4 I noticed there was no sound at all (Rythmbox, games, etc). And I found no icon anywhere to adjust the sound.

This is how I did to fix the problem :

1) Go to the applications menu > Sound & Video > Mixer.

2) In the Sound Card option menu, select Playback: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo (PulseAudio Mixer).

3) The playback window may be empty. Click on "Select Controls..." , enable/check Master then close.

4) Unmute the sound icon just under the volume bar.

I guess you need to check whether you are using PulseAudio or Alsa drivers. This should not change the fact you need to uncheck mute icon in your "Playback: Audio stereo" in Mixer.

I hope this can help :-)

PS : I am a newbie in linux stuff, so please correct me if I said something wrong.